# What is HTTP/2's protocol id and why are there so many of them?

Tags: http, terminology, http2

I'm learning HTTP/2. I know there's [RFC7540](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#SettingsSync) which is the specification of HTTP/2. But I got confused by the term "protocol id" shown on the [implementation page](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations). There are `h2`, `h2c`, `h2-14`, `h2-15`, `h2-16`, `h2-17`, `h2c-17`(not sure I listed all).

What are these protocol ids? What's the relationship between them and RFC7540?

What does it mean if some HTTP/2 server implementation claims to support(?) some protocol id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RFC7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) was published in May 2015. It describes **h2** and **h2c**. Before the publication there are 17 draft publications:

- February 11, 2015 - [draft 17](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-17)
- November 29, 2014 - [draft 16](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-16)
- October 27, 2014 - [draft 15](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-15)
- July 30, 2014 - [draft 14](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-14)
- ...

Some web servers included support of HTTP2 starting with some draft version. Some web server supports still preliminary versions of the protocol together with supporting of the final version. The names **h2-17, h2c-17, h2-16, h2c-16**, ... are used to specify **h2 or h2c from the corresponding draft specification**.

Comment: Why do they still need to support draft versions since the final version is out? For compatibility reason?

Comment: @laike9m: Sorry, but it's too detailed question. The reason could be *different for every web server*. Many web server available for free and an clean-up of existing code will take only time and gives no money for web developers. You can investigate the exact differences between draft standards by examining of [the differences](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcdiff?url2=rfc7540), but which practical value it has? Much more important to the most readers of your question is the fact that **h2-16 and h2-17 not new standards** (16 and 17 means not 2016 and 2017 for example). Isn't so?